# arrange numbers into 3 groups (by sum) in an ordered list

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am looking for a way to group numbers into 3 groups, which each group has a sum as close to others as possible.  And the order of original list is preserved.

For example , here is a list:

```
5,7,2,4,3,10
I should group them into (5,7) (2,4,3) (10)
the sum for each group is (12) (9) (10)
```

My initial thought is to add up until one group is greater than Sum/3, then move to next. But the above list will become:

```
edit: wrong number used, sorry for the error.
avg=10.3
groups: (5,72) (4,3,10) ()
```

I am thinking about adding more conditions to the addup process, But there are always edge cases not covered.  As a stubborn programmer, I'd wish to have something working intrinsically correct rather than relying on conditions to cover edge cases.

The original problem:
Trying to arrange a number of tables into 3 columns layout without breaking individual tables.  Then each column should have similar height.  The numbers in the example represent the height of each table.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the greedy algorithm?

Comment: The above list does not become `(5,7) (2,4) (3,10)` as you state.  $\text{Sum}/3$ is equal to $10.\overline{3}$, so in fact you would either get `(5,7) (2,4, 3, 10) ()`  (if adding up each group individually until it passed 10.3) or `(5,7) (2,4,3) (10)` (if considering the total sum so far and breaking off when it passes $\text{Sum}/3$ and $2\cdot\text{Sum}/3$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that two of your groups have sum less than $\frac {Sum}3$, and at least one of them will.  So you should consider placing the breaks just before or just after you cross $\frac {Sum}3$  For the first group, you would then have the possibility of $5$ or $5,7$.  In the first case, you can then have $7,2$ or $7,2,4$  In the second, you can have $2,4,3$ or $2,4,3,10$.  So the choices are $$\begin {array} {r|r|r|r|r}first&second&third&max sum&min sum\\\hline 5&7,2&4,3,10&17&5\\ 5&7,2,4&3,10&13&5\\5,7&2,4,3&10&12&9\\5,7&2,4,3,10&error&\end{array}$$ and you can choose the best one.

Comment: this looks better, and not computational expensive.  I'll try it out in the program tonight.  Post back later.